# Zabbix file last modify date check problem

Tags: file, date, zabbix

I added to my zabbix (4.2.5) this ITEM

```
vfs.file.time[/home/PATH_TO_FILE/MY.log,modify]
```

And I receive this error "Cannot obtain file information: [13] Permission denied"

But if i log on VM to test and launch command

```
zabbix_agentd -t "vfs.file.time[/home/PATH_TO_FILE/MY.log,modify]"
```

agent return "**[u|1595559607]**" correct data.

So I tryed to run agent command as zabbix user....

```
runuser -l zabbix -c 'zabbix_agentd -t "vfs.file.time[/home/PATH_TO_FILE/MY.log,modify]"'
```

**runuser: warning: cannot change directory to /var/lib/zabbix: File o directory not exists
This account is currently not available.**

becouse zabbix agent user is

```
zabbix:x:997:995:Zabbix Monitoring System:/var/lib/zabbix:/sbin/nologin
```

Zabbix agent is latest 5.x

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

- which user are you logged in as, and which user is Zabbix Agent running as?
- which permission has the file, and the container folders?
- you can't use  `runas -l zabbix` because user is locked, you should use

  - from the zabbix server (or proxy): `zabbix_get -s ip/hostname -k vfs.file.time[/home/PATH_TO_FILE/MY.log,modify]`
  - from the monitored host: `su - zabbix -s /bin/sh -c 'zabbix_agentd -t "vfs.file.time[/home/PATH_TO_FILE/MY.log,modify]"'`

Comment: Agent run as zabbix user (As installed by yum)

I did method 2 (on the monitored host) and I received

 [m|ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED] [Cannot obtain file information: [13] Permission denied]

The entire path to the log file always has read permissions for everyone.

Also I tested with a fake log file in /tmp/folder and works!

So I think it's a permission problem, but why?

Comment: try with `su - zabbix -s /bin/sh -c 'ls -l /home /home/PATH /home/PATH_TO_FILE/MY.log'`

Comment: Hi Iron, I did.
/home ok, /home/firstPath no access also if permission is 755.
I changed permission to 750 and then again to 755 and now works! Also subfolders.
So why?

Comment: It's haunted. Or, selinux is trolling.